# Airflow: Access template field from upstream task

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, airflow

I have two tasks, one is a custom operator where it has one template field (`snapshot_date_str`)and it will set the field in "xcom", and the other operator is `S3Sensor` and the `bucket_key` requires the template field which was set in the first task.

Dag definition:

```
SNAPSHOT_DATE = datetime.now().date()
S3_BUCKET = 'test-s3'
TENANT = 'test'

dag = DAG('template_fields_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='@hourly',
          concurrency=1,
          catchup=False)

t1 = ContextInitOperator(task_id='set_context', snapshot_date=SNAPSHOT_DATE, tenant=TENANT, dag=dag)

file_task = S3KeySensor(task_id="s3_file_sensor",
                        aws_conn_id='s3_connection',
                        bucket_key='test/{{ snapshot_date_str }}/abc.csv',
                        bucket_name=S3_BUCKET,
                        wildcard_match=True,
                        poke_interval=10,
                        timeout=60,
                        dag=dag)
t1 >> file_task
```

And my custom `ContextInitOperator` sets the template field `snapshot_date_str` in xcom.

```
class ContextInitOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = ('snapshot_date_str',)

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            snapshot_date,
            *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContextInitOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.snapshot_date_str = snapshot_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    def execute(self, context):
        context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='snapshot_date_str', value=self.snapshot_date_str)
```

The `bucket_key` requires the `snapshot_date_str` in the path.

I am not comfortable with Python and Airflow yet, am I missing something basic? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms), you might have to do something in the lines of

```
bucket_key="test/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='set_context', key='snapshot_date_str') }}/abc.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for getting the formatted date, Airflow can help you there. Depending on your needs you can use the following, predefined variables:

```
bucket_key='test/{{ ds }}/abc.csv',
```

for today,

```
bucket_key='test/{{ yesterday_ds }}/abc.csv',
```

for yesterday and

```
bucket_key='test/{{ tomorrow_ds }}/abc.csv',
```

for tomorrow. See all usable macros here: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros

This means that your `ContextInitOperator` could be removed.

`bucket_key` is also a templated field as can be seen in the source file (https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/sensors.html) so using Jinja variables will work.

Date handling is done a bit differently in Airflow, so you might need to experiment to get the outcome you need (from https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/scheduler.html):

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was using `{{ ds }}` and `{{ execution_time }}` but was not able to convert into right timezone. I was also looking for any general xcom information that can be passed in templates to non `PythonOperators`.